# Get text not rapped on a div

Tags: html, jquery

im trying to get some text without having any wrapping element, a example is:

```
<div class="theme">
<h3>Title</h3>
Get text here
<table>
...
</table>

</div>
```

Thats basically the structure of the html, im tyring to figure out how to get the text "Get text here", is there any helpfull funcition in jquery to make this task easyer?

Comment: Why can't you have any kind of wrapping element? This makes your job much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: nop i cant unfortanly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of objects are known as `node` in JavaScript. `nextSibling` and `prevSibling` properties show next and previous node. for example, you can find `h3` and then use `nextSibling` or find the `table` and then use `prevSibling` (as the following code).

For nodes `wholeText` property is the same as `innerText` and gives the content of the node.

```
var h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
console.log(h3.nextSibling)
console.log(h3.nextSibling.wholeText)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine!